# 2 Audio Players Independently from each other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-audio-api

I'm trying to adapt someone's code from codepen.io that made this pretty visual audio player playlist. My goal I want to achieve is to have multiple of these on a single page since the original code only supported one. I'm trying to figure out how to get these audio players to behave on their own accord rather than, when I press play on one it will pause the previous or vice versa. At the moment, the problem is that they're all sharing the same audio controls and I'm trying to figure out a way to target each audio player uniquely.

Been trying at this for a couple days so I'm reaching out for help. My initial thought which you'll see in the codepen.io below was to wrap each div of the audio player in its own unique div. Then in JS, call an array of the divs and with forEach iterate the JS function for the audio playlist on each div. I know there is something wrong with my functions or perhaps my approach in general and I would love to have some feedback and direction.

Currently, I have just two audio players to start with so I can even see if my idea is working. Right now their both accessing the same songs/album covers, however I just wanted to figure out how to get them to play differently first before figuring out the rest of the stuff haha. So apologies if you notice that problem too.

[2 Audio Players Independently -- Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/dmdcomposer/pen/dyRYqJg)

Lastly, I'm implementing this with some AHK scripts & Edge/IE, so I'm forced for the time being to use Legacy JS.

Thank you. Cheers!

Here is the code for the JS in case you don't want to visit codepen.io.

```js
let musicPlayers = [
  {
    audioPlayer: ".audio-1",
    trackInfo: [
      {
        song: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/1.mp3",
        title: "Dawn",
        album: "Skylike - Dawn",
        art: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_1.jpg",
      },
      {
        song: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/2.mp3",
        title: "Me & You",
        album: "Alex Skrindo - Me & You",
        art: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_2.jpg",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    audioPlayer: ".audio-2",
    trackInfo: [
      {
        song: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/3.mp3",
        title: "Electro Boy",
        album: "Kaaze - Electro Boy",
        art: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_3.jpg",
      },
      {
        song: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/music/4.mp3",
        title: "Home",
        album: "Martin Garrix - Home",
        art: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/himalayasingh/music-player-1/master/img/_5.jpg",
      },
    ],
  },
]

console.log("number of audio players:", musicPlayers.length)
musicPlayers.forEach(function (musicPlayer, index) {
  let tracksObj = { song: [], title: [], album: [], art: [] }
  musicPlayer.trackInfo.forEach(function (track) {
    tracksObj.song.push(track.song)
    tracksObj.title.push(track.title)
    tracksObj.album.push(track.album)
    tracksObj.art.push(track.art)
  })
  console.log(tracksObj.art)
  // console.log(index, musicPlayer.trackInfo[0].song)
  $(function () {
    let playerTrack = $(
        musicPlayer.audioPlayer + " > #app-cover > #player > #player-track"
      ),
      bgArtwork = $(musicPlayer.audioPlayer + " > #app-cover > #bg-artwork"),
      bgArtworkUrl,
      albumName = playerTrack.children("#album-name"),
      trackName = playerTrack.children("#track-name"),
      trackTime = playerTrack.children("#track-time"),
      tProgress = trackTime.children("#current-time"),
      tTime = trackTime.children("#track-length"),
      sArea = playerTrack.children("#s-area"),
      insTime = sArea.children("#ins-time"),
      sHover = sArea.children("#s-hover"),
      seekBar = sArea.children("#seek-bar"),
      playerContent = $(
        musicPlayer.audioPlayer + " > #app-cover > #player > #player-content"
      ),
      albumArt = playerContent.children("#album-art"),
      playerControls = playerContent.children("#player-controls"),
      playPauseButton = playerControls
        .children(".control")
        .children("#play-pause-button"),
      i = playPauseButton.find("i"),
      seekT,
      seekLoc,
      seekBarPos,
      cM,
      ctMinutes,
      ctSeconds,
      curMinutes,
      curSeconds,
      durMinutes,
      durSeconds,
      playProgress,
      bTime,
      nTime = 0,
      buffInterval = null,
      tFlag = false,
      albums = tracksObj.album,
      trackNames = tracksObj.title,
      albumArtworks = tracksObj.art,
      trackUrl = tracksObj.song,
      playPreviousTrackButton = playerControls
        .children(".control")
        .children("#play-previous"),
      playNextTrackButton = playerControls
        .children(".control")
        .children("#play-next"),
      currIndex = -1

    function playPause() {
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (audio.paused) {
          playerTrack.addClass("active")
          albumArt.addClass("active")
          checkBuffering()
          i.attr("class", "fas fa-pause")
          audio.play()
          console.log(currIndex)
        } else {
          playerTrack.removeClass("active")
          albumArt.removeClass("active")
          clearInterval(buffInterval)
          albumArt.removeClass("buffering")
          i.attr("class", "fas fa-play")
          audio.pause()
        }
      }, 300)
    }

    function showHover(event) {
      seekBarPos = sArea.offset()
      seekT = event.clientX - seekBarPos.left
      seekLoc = audio.duration * (seekT / sArea.outerWidth())

      sHover.width(seekT)

      cM = seekLoc / 60

      ctMinutes = Math.floor(cM)
      ctSeconds = Math.floor(seekLoc - ctMinutes * 60)

      if (ctMinutes < 0 || ctSeconds < 0) return

      if (ctMinutes < 0 || ctSeconds < 0) return

      if (ctMinutes < 10) ctMinutes = "0" + ctMinutes
      if (ctSeconds < 10) ctSeconds = "0" + ctSeconds

      if (isNaN(ctMinutes) || isNaN(ctSeconds)) insTime.text("--:--")
      else insTime.text(ctMinutes + ":" + ctSeconds)

      insTime.css({ left: seekT, "margin-left": "-21px" }).fadeIn(0)
    }

    function hideHover() {
      sHover.width(0)
      insTime
        .text("00:00")
        .css({ left: "0px", "margin-left": "0px" })
        .fadeOut(0)
    }

    function playFromClickedPos() {
      audio.currentTime = seekLoc
      seekBar.width(seekT)
      hideHover()
    }

    function updateCurrTime() {
      nTime = new Date()
      nTime = nTime.getTime()

      if (!tFlag) {
        tFlag = true
        trackTime.addClass("active")
      }

      curMinutes = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60)
      curSeconds = Math.floor(audio.currentTime - curMinutes * 60)

      durMinutes = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60)
      durSeconds = Math.floor(audio.duration - durMinutes * 60)

      playProgress = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100

      if (curMinutes < 10) curMinutes = "0" + curMinutes
      if (curSeconds < 10) curSeconds = "0" + curSeconds

      if (durMinutes < 10) durMinutes = "0" + durMinutes
      if (durSeconds < 10) durSeconds = "0" + durSeconds

      if (isNaN(curMinutes) || isNaN(curSeconds)) tProgress.text("00:00")
      else tProgress.text(curMinutes + ":" + curSeconds)

      if (isNaN(durMinutes) || isNaN(durSeconds)) tTime.text("00:00")
      else tTime.text(durMinutes + ":" + durSeconds)

      if (
        isNaN(curMinutes) ||
        isNaN(curSeconds) ||
        isNaN(durMinutes) ||
        isNaN(durSeconds)
      )
        trackTime.removeClass("active")
      else trackTime.addClass("active")

      seekBar.width(playProgress + "%")

      if (playProgress == 100) {
        i.attr("class", "fa fa-play")
        seekBar.width(0)
        tProgress.text("00:00")
        albumArt.removeClass("buffering").removeClass("active")
        clearInterval(buffInterval)
      }
    }

    function checkBuffering() {
      clearInterval(buffInterval)
      buffInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (nTime == 0 || bTime - nTime > 1000) albumArt.addClass("buffering")
        else albumArt.removeClass("buffering")

        bTime = new Date()
        bTime = bTime.getTime()
      }, 100)
    }

    function selectTrack(flag) {
      // console.log("flag = ", flag)
      if (flag == 0 || flag == 1) ++currIndex
      else --currIndex

      if (currIndex > -1 && currIndex < albumArtworks.length) {
        if (flag == 0) i.attr("class", "fa fa-play")
        else {
          albumArt.removeClass("buffering")
          i.attr("class", "fa fa-pause")
        }

        seekBar.width(0)
        trackTime.removeClass("active")
        tProgress.text("00:00")
        tTime.text("00:00")

        currAlbum = albums[currIndex]
        currTrackName = trackNames[currIndex]
        currArtwork = albumArtworks[currIndex]

        audio.src = trackUrl[currIndex]

        nTime = 0
        bTime = new Date()
        bTime = bTime.getTime()

        if (flag != 0) {
          audio.play()
          playerTrack.addClass("active")
          albumArt.addClass("active")

          clearInterval(buffInterval)
          checkBuffering()
        }

        albumName.text(currAlbum)
        trackName.text(currTrackName)
        albumArt.find("img.active").removeClass("active")
        albumArt.find("#current-album-art").addClass("active")
        albumArt.find("img.active").attr("src", currArtwork)

        bgArtworkUrl = albumArt.find("img.active").attr("src")

        bgArtwork.css({ "background-image": "url(" + bgArtworkUrl + ")" })
      } else {
        if (flag == 0 || flag == 1) --currIndex
        else ++currIndex
      }
    }

    function initPlayer() {
      // audio = new Audio()
      audio = document.createElement("audio")

      selectTrack(0)

      audio.loop = false

      playPauseButton.on("click", playPause)

      sArea.mousemove(function (event) {
        showHover(event)
      })

      sArea.mouseout(hideHover)

      sArea.on("click", playFromClickedPos)

      $(audio).on("timeupdate", updateCurrTime)

      playPreviousTrackButton.on("click", function () {
        selectTrack(-1)
        console.log(currIndex)
      })
      playNextTrackButton.on("click", function () {
        selectTrack(1)
      })
    }

    initPlayer()
  })
})
```

Comment: You are accessing the children by their ID. They don't have a fitting class to select? If the player uses IDs it probably means it does not support being reused multiple times.

Comment: Ah okay. I can switch everything to unqiue classes. I guess my thought process was if I wrapped each audio in its own div it would be fine. But let me switch everything to classes and see if that helps. Ty!

Comment: If it doesn't resolve the problem at least that's better anyway. Good luck.

Comment: Can't promise anything, but do you have the link to the codepen for the music player where you got the code from?

Comment: @DanZuzevich , hi yes! Here is the link:

https://codepen.io/himalayasingh/pen/QZKqOX

Comment: Is your code going to be dynamically creating these players? For example, you won't just be copy and pasting a bunch of audio player html into a file, say if you wanted 5 players?

Comment: I'm leaning towards dynamically creating them and inserting them into the DOM via JS.

Comment: @DanZuzevich Yes, that's why I tried to simulate it with my musicPlayers object. I will be dynamically calling/inserting new audioplayer(s) like you said.

Comment: Alright, I found the problem. I will post an answer that solves getting the players to play independently. If you need help with making things more dynamic, and creating all these html elements with JS, it might be worth posting another question related to just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've figured out why the players won't play independently, and it seems to be related to some type of JS scoping issue, and how the audio variable was being assigned in the `init` function. I'm still not exactly sure why, but it seems as every audio player created was referencing the same exact audio instance.

If you change two things, then it should work for you.

First, at the very beginning of the immediately invoked function expression, declare an audio variable, set to nothing.

```
 $(function () {
    let audio, playerTrack = $(
        musicPlayer.audioPlayer + " > #app-cover > #player > #player-track"
      ),
    ...rest of code
```

Next, go into the `init` function, and change the code from this:

```
// audio = new Audio()
audio = document.createElement("audio")
```

to this:

```
audio = new Audio()
```

This is bugging me, because in theory it looks like a new audio instance should have been assigned to each, but apparently not. Anyways...this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much Dan. I appreciate you taking the time and explaining. This is perfect and getting me to move forward with my script. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. If you have any other questions, feel free to post the link to them here.